Let $n=pq$, where $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod 4$. Let $Q$ be the set of quadratic residue mod n, then $pm\in Q$ if and only if $-pm\in Q$.
I checked some cases and found that $pm\in Q$ whenever $p(q-m)\in Q$, $0\leq m\leq q$. I tried to prove it but I couldn't. After some failed attempt I observed that if both $pm$ and $p(q-m)$ are elements of $Q$, then there exists integers $a$ and $b$ such that $q \mid (a^2+b^2)$. I am not being able to use this fact to conclude my hypothesis. I don't know whether this is a good approach.
I also found (from the examples I checked) that number of elements of form $pm$ in $Q$ is exactly $\frac{q+1}{2}$. Though I could not prove this as well. I know that $|Q|=\frac{(p+1)(q+1)}{4}$.
I will be grateful for any help. It will be even better if someone suggests me any book for reading these stuff.

Assu ing $p$ and $q$ are primes: $x$ is a square mod $n$ if and only if it is a square mod $p$ and mod $q$. Since $-1$ is a square mod $q$, $pm$ is a square mod $q$ if and only if $-pm$ is a square mod $q$. Both are $0$ mod $p$, hence squares.

Thank you. I could get to it using Chinese Remainder Theorem. But your answer is even simpler.
